# I think my css classes the are imported but I have imported it correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, project

This is a burger builder project which I have been working on, here  my error is in using  css class file in the burger builder controls .

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './BuildControls.css';
import BuildControl from './BuildControl/BuildControl';
const controls = [
    {label : 'Salad' , type :'salad'},
    {label : 'Bacon' , type :'bacon'},
    {label : 'Cheese' , type :'cheese'},
    {label : 'Meat' , type :'meat'},
];
const buildControls =(props) => { 
    <div className = {classes.BuildControls}>
        {controls.map(ctrl =>(
            <BuildControl Key ={ctrl.label} label={ctrl.label}/>
        ))}
    </div>
}

export default buildControls;
```

THE ERROR IS

> ./src/components /Burger /BuildControls/BuildControls.js
>
> Line 11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: may be declaring css file name as `BuildControls.module.css` instade of `BuildControls.css` can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
const buildControls =(props) => {
return (
 <div className = {classes.BuildControls}>
    {controls.map(ctrl =>(
        <BuildControl Key ={ctrl.label} label={ctrl.label}/>
    )))}
 </div>
}
```

you need to return the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the css as follows:

```
import './BuildControls.css';
```

And then use the class as follows:

```
<div className="BuildControls">
</div>
```

Note: I am assuming your classname in the css file is `BuildControls`